# .NET 4.0 and 4.5.1 on one server, giving issues?

Tags: asp.net, .net

Can .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5.1 runtime be installed on one application server so that web apps targeting .NET 4.0 and web apps targeting .NET 4.5.1 will be running smoothly ?

(I heard from collegaes that 4.5.1 will break 4.0 apps after 4.5.1 is installed...)

Comment: You may find your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16089883/2174170)

Comment: It should work fine. Imagine if this is what happened. As an end user I'd install .NET 4.5.1 and now my existing apps don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No** there is no such way as of now.(that mean what you have heard from your colleagues is quite right!) I think it is a known issue and yes 4.5.1 overwrites 4.5 so make sure you have the same version installed on your development machine and on the server. You may definitely get some more info of your problem in this **[MSDN blog](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c05a8c02-de67-47a9-b4ed-fd8b622a7e4a/if-i-target-net-40-but-run-on-a-machine-that-has-net-45-will-net-40-wpf-bugs-still-be-there?forum=wpf)** and this [MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2890857)

> Because if you develop "Targeting .NET 4.0", then you clearly plan to
>   run on a machine that DOES NOT HAVE .NET 4.5!

You need to target the .Net4.0 framework to get rid of your problem